# readonly filesystem after reboot

Tags: archlinux, filesystem

I use ArchLinux on Raspberry Pi B+. If I reboot it using `shutdown -r`, I always get readonly filesystem after reboot and I have to remoung it using `sudo mount -o remount,rw /`. Isn't `shutdown -r` graceful reboot regarding to filesystems? The version is `Linux computer001 3.18.3-3-ARCH #1 PREEMPT Mon Jan 26 20:10:28 MST 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux`.

Comment: You should have a look in your logs and see if there's some explanation there.  I've noticed some inconsistencies WRT to shutdown/reboot behaviour following firmware upgrades, although not this specifically.

Comment: @goldilocks, I haven't found anything relevant regarding filesystem.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In /boot/cmdline.txt, add rw just before rootwait

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem. But why wasn't it necessary before?

Comment: This also fixed my problem. I got this issue after updating Raspbian from Wheezy to Jessie. Jessie moved me over to systemd, so I suspect there was something at boot that had previously remounted my filesystem as rw automatically. In my understanding, it isn't abnormal to mount `/` as `ro` then later in the boot process remounting it as `rw` (so that the system can `fsck` the filesystem if it wants). Perhaps `/etc/init.d/checkroot.sh` or `/etc/init.d/mountkernfs.sh` was where it was getting remounted?